# Find special character in last line of text file

Tags: bash, grep

I have a text file like this (e.g., `a.txt`):

```
 1.1.t     
 1.2.m
```

If the last line consists of the character `m`, I want to echo `Ok`.

I tried this:

```
line=` awk '/./{line=$0} END{print line}'  a.txt`     
line1= `echo $line | grep "m"`       
if [[ $line1= `:` ]] ; then
echo
else
echo "Ok"
fi
```

It does not work, and the error  is:

```
bash: conditional binary operator expected
bash: syntax error near ``:`,
`if [[ $line1= `:` ]] ; then'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if [[ $line1=`:`]]` is incorrect syntax in couple of ways as spaces around `=` are missing and backtick is used for command substitution

awk itself can handle this:

```
awk '/./{line=$0} END{print (line ~ /\.m/)? "ok" : "no"}' file
ok
```

Comment: `awk '/./{line=$0} END{print (line ~ /\.m/)? "ok" : "no"}' file`     I try this for non-blank line. thanks. it works

Comment: I've updated a version that takes care of empty lines.

Comment: If the line consists of a single character, `0`, the first condition will evaluate to false even though the line is not blank.

Comment: You can use double backticks to surround inline code containing single backticks: ``if [[ $line1=`:` ]]``

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `tail` and `grep`:

```
[[ -n $(tail -1 a.txt | grep "m$") ]] && echo "OK" || echo "FAILED"
```

Comment: You don't really need `grep` here: `if [[ $(tail -1 a.txt) = *m ]]; then echo "OK"; else echo "FAILED"; fi`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf You're right. Still keeping it as it is to show the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -n '${/m$/s/.*/OK/p;}' file
```

The option `-n` suppresses output by default. `$` addresses the last line of input. In that case we check if the line ends with `m` through `/m$/`. If that is the case we substitute the line with the word `OK` and print it.

Btw, I was going trough your shell script, there are really too many errors to explain, the syntax error is because there is no space between `$line1` and the `=` in the `[[ ... ]]` conditional. But hey, this is far from being the only problem with that script. ;)

http://www.shellcheck.net/ might be a good resource to enhance your scripts.

Comment: This generates an error: `sed: 1: "${/m$/s/.*/OK/p}": bad flag in substitute command: '}'` when run in non-GNU sed (OSX, FreeBSD, perhaps others).  Add a semicolon before the final `}` to make it portable.

Comment: @ghoti I'm using GNU sed. That works for me even if I pass `--posix`. Does it work for you with the semicolon after `p` ?

Comment: Yes, it does - with the semicolon, your script works both in GNU sed and non-GNU. The issue is not POSIX compliance, it's that GNU is more forgiving about where it assumes line breaks should occur. The `p` is the end of a command. Think of the `}` as a *different command*, not just a wrapper providing structure. It's not a structured language, sed is more of a state machine.

Comment: Ok, added that. I think I've also hear about `sed`'s which require the `{}` to appear on a new line. If I remember correctly even posix says that. Looks like the `--posix` mode is not fully posix complete.